# c++/cli custom exception - standard constructors

Tags: .net-4.0, c++-cli

Trying to avoid the FxCop warning 'Do not raise reserved exceptions' from a C++/CLI library so I decided to break down and write my own exception type.

```
[Serializable]
public ref class CaptureException : public Exception
{
public:
    CaptureException() : Exception() {}
    CaptureException(String^ message) : Exception(message) {}
    CaptureException(String^ message, Exception^ inner) : Exception(message, inner) {}
protected:
    CaptureException(System::Runtime::Serialization::SerializationInfo^ info, System::Runtime::Serialization::StreamingContext^ context) : Exception(info, context) {}
};
```

This doesn't compile stating

```
error C2664: 'System::Exception::Exception(System::String ^,System::Exception ^)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'System::Runtime::Serialization::SerializationInfo ^' to 'System::String ^'
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting this error. Does the C++/CLI not have the full exception class? I'm just trying to implement the standard constructors for my exception and in C# it looks like this and compiles fine.

```
[Serializable]
public class CaptureException : Exception
{
    public DatabaseConnectionException() { }
    public CaptureException (string message) : base(message) { }
    public CaptureException (string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
    protected CaptureException (
      System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info,
      System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext context)
        : base(info, context) { }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

StreamingContext is a value type (i.e. a struct), so you'll want to remove the hat ^:

```
    CaptureException(System::Runtime::Serialization::SerializationInfo^ info, System::Runtime::Serialization::StreamingContext context) : Exception(info, context) 
{}
```

Comment: Beat me by a minute, as I was brushing up on my C++/CLI just to answer this. :)

Comment: @AdamMaras, Ha--that happens to *me* all the time.  It's nice to finally be the winner ;).  I wish there was a way to see how many people are currently working on an answer before I started in on it.

Comment: Well, 'grats. You deserved it. I had to figure out whether there was any modifier I had to put on a CLI value type (like ^ for a managed handle, % for a tracking reference, etc..) but as soon as I figured out there wasn't, I saw your answer.

Comment: Awesome thanks that worked. Why wouldn't the compiler give a warning for incorrectly marking value types as ref types? This seems like it would be a pretty common mistake.

Comment: @NtscCobalt : Because it's not illegal; adding `^` to a value type causes it to be implicitly boxed, which is a _feature_ of the language.